# assembly reference missing on moving to live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Trying to put my latest build up from Visual studio 2008 local code to my live server and I am now getting a error

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IndexModelView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


public class views_bpladmin_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IndexModelView>, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
```

ive tried taking everything onto the live server as well as doing the method of publishing to a folder and putting that up. So all references should be up without a problem. I'm only having this problem on one page, Of which uses the IndexModelView which im guessing is something to do with it!

Comment: Are your viewmodels in the same project as everything else? Could be that if they are in a separate project, the reference is using the file path from your dev machine i.e. something like C:/Documents and Settings... which doesn't work on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are missing the assembly (as it sounds like it is probably an assembly that is part of your solution).  The other likely issue is that your web.config(s) have a namespace in them on your local machine that your production web.config file doesn't have.

Look for a section in your web.config that looks similar to:

```
<pages>
<namespaces>
...
</namespaces>
</pages>
```

And make sure the namespace that class is in is included in the list.  If you are using Razor, then the section will look slightly different and may be in a web.config file in a subdirectory (like the Views directory).